# How do I setup two curl commands to execute at different times forever?

Tags: linux, bash

For example, I want to run one command every 10 seconds and the other command every 5 minutes. I can only get the first one to log properly to a text file. Below is the shell script I am working on:

```
echo "script Running. Press CTRL-C to stop the process..."
while sleep 10;
do
curl -s -I --http2 https://www.ubuntu.com/ >> new.txt
echo "------------1st command--------------------"  >> logs.txt;
done
||
while sleep 300;
do
curl -s -I --http2 https://www.google.com/
echo "-----------------------2nd command---------------------------" >> logs.txt;
done
```

Comment: Is having a single loop, which downloads the first URL 30 times (using an inner loop) then downloading the second URL once, before repeating the whole process, an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to go with @Marvin Crone's answer, but researching cronjobs and back-ground processes doesn't seem like the kind of hassle I would go through for this little script. Instead, try putting both loops into separate scripts; like so:

script1.sh

```
echo "job 1 Running. Type fg 1 and press CTRL-C to stop the process..."
while sleep 10;
do
echo $(curl -s -I --http2 https://www.ubuntu.com/)  >> logs.txt;
done
```

script2.sh

```
echo "job 2 Running. Type fg 2 and press CTRL-C to stop the process..."
while sleep 300;
do
echo $(curl -s -I --http2 https://www.google.com/) >> logs.txt;
done
```

adding executable permissions

```
chmod +x script1.sh
chmod +x script2.sh
```

and last but not least running them:

```
./script1.sh & ./script2.sh &
```

this creates two separate jobs in the background that you can call by typing:

```
fg (1 or 2)
```

and stop them with CTRL-C or send them to background again by typing CTRL-Z

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that you start the first loop.  Your first loop needs to complete before the second loop will start.  But, the first loop is designed to be infinite.
I suggest you put each curl loop in a separate batch file.
Then, you can run each batch file separately, in the background.
I offer two suggestions for you to investigate for your solution.
One, research the use of crontab and set up a cron job to run the batch files.
Two, research the use of nohup as a means of running the batch files.
I strongly suggest you also research the means of monitoring the jobs and knowing how to terminate the jobs if anything goes wrong.  You are setting up infinite loops.  A simple Control C will not terminate jobs running in the background.  You are treading in areas that can get out of control.  You need to know what you are doing.